# Query multiple columns on a given value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in my database (postgres)
Table #1

```
----------------------------------------------------    
| name  |  id_a |  id_b | id_c | id_d |  id_e | id_f    
----------------------------------------------------
```

I am now given a list of ids. Some of these ids belong to id_b, some to id_c and so on till id_f. 
For these list of ids I need to find the corresponding id_a.

Method #1
Identify which ids belong to id_b, id_c and so on. 
Then use multiple in clause in my mysql-query to fetch id_a

```
select id_a from Table #1 t1 where t1.id_b in () or t1.id_c in ().... or t1.id_f in ();
```

I am looking for an alternative way.

Method #2

Is there some way to query all the columns simultaneously for a given value. Something like

```
select id_a from Table #1 t1 where t1.id_b,t1.id_c,..t1.id_f in ();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In postgres, you can use the array-overlap, `&&`, operator:

```
SELECT id_a
FROM   mytable
WHERE  ARRAY[id_b, id_c, id_d, id_e, id_f] && ARRAY[value1, value2, ...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Yesss, you can do it like

```
SELECT columnA
FROM tableA
WHERE (columnA, columnB, columnC)::text IN ('TEST', 'TEST2');
```

The cast `::text` may be required

Comment: `(columnA, columnB, columnC)::text` groups the columns together so your output looks like `valueA,valueB,valueC` if you want to make this work it needs to be `LIKE ('%TEST%')` not sure performance vs an alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

you can use union

```
select * from t where id_a in (

select * from 
(select id_b  from t union
select id_c from t union
select id_d from t union
select id_e from t union
select id_f from t
 ) as t1
)
```